# What's the difference between these thre way to stop a Jenkins pipeline?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

What's the difference between these thre way to stop a Jenkins pipeline?

1. `BUILD ID URL/stop`
2. `BUILD ID URL/term`
3. `BUILD ID URL/kill`

Are there any pipeline examples?

Comment: Please add as many examples, and as much information as you can to your question.